# cross index script for elastic saerch

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

Can I write a script on elastic search and share it across multiple indices on same elastic search server?
I know we can write scripts for index: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html, but is it possible to create index agnostic script?
My specific use case is that I have some tenant id to name mapping, multiple indices on elastic search uses same list of tenant ids. and they log the tenant id to elastic search, I want to create a scripted field user-friendly/readable tenant name which can be generated from 1:1 mapping from tenant id. I am able to do this for specific index, but it means I have to copy this script across indices and whenever new tenant is added I have to update it everywhere. Is there a simpler way to handle this?